# Unity Ragdoll Colliders don't collide

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I have a humanoid character with Ragdoll setup in Unity. However the box/capsule colliders on the various parts of the body don't collide with other static geometry. They do collide with the ground but not with any other static meshes. Is it possible to use them as colliders towards static meshes and what do I need to do for it to work?

Comment: Rigidbodies should collide with static mesh colliders by default. Recommend you review the [colliders overview](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html), [rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html), and [mesh collider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) manual pages to check if you've missed some details. Have you marked the rigidbodies as kinematic or put them on a different layer?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that they might both be mesh colliders, if so they need to be marked convex.

Its also possible that the static meshes might not have colliders attached.

Comment: The static geometry has a mesh collider. If I set it to convex my character falls right through the floor. If I add an additional large capsule collider around my char she does collide but walks like a drunk on eggs. And I'd prefer not to use an additional large collider. If possible collision should work only with the ragdoll colliders.

Comment: I would suspect then that the ragdoll colliders are not setup properly. 
Try using this free tool rather than the built in one and see if you get the same result 
http://unity.thearcgames.com/URG!_Ultimate_Ragdoll_Generator

Comment: So they are definitely supposed to collide with static meshes without further doings? Then I will try the tool you've linked. Although my ragdoll setup looks fairly correct as far as I see.

Comment: Well I've tried URG! but it's too confusing for me so I instead went with another ragdoll asset named Ragdoll Workshop. While it's a quality tool it didn't help fix my issue: Even when I setup a ragdoll character with RW the ragdoll colliders still don't collide with static objects. And if I don't put a rigidbody on my character I cannot move her.

Comment: @BadmintonCat it sounds like the static objects dont have colliders or dont have them setup properly. 

I know the URG code can be pretty complex, Ive never been able to figure out some features of it (Like dismemberment) Every so often I go back to it and think Ive got it figured out, and never do. But the actual ragdoll generator is pretty solid and easy to use I thought. 

Maybe post some screen shots of how the ragdolls and static meshes are set up.

Answer (score 1):

Every 2 objects that collide need to have at least 1 rigidbody between them. Both need some type of collider component, such as mesh, cube, cylinder